# creating a twitter like auto suggest search box in rails

Tags: jquery, twitter, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2, autosuggest

please those anyone know how to create a twitter or facebook like auto-suggest search box? i have been trying to implement this for a while now...here is some code i got from [enter link description here](http://s254.codeinspot.com/q/1379267).

```
 <div class="search_index">


 <div id = "testsearch">
 <%=render :partial => 'search'%> // partial where the updated search elements will appear from 
 </div>

<%=form_tag(search_path,:method=>'get',:remote=>true) do%>

   <%=text_field_tag :search%>
   <%= submit_tag "search" ,:name=>nil%>

<%end%>

<%= set_focus_to_id 'search' %>  // I have a helper "set_focus_to_id"



<script> // small javascript file :)

 document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {   // ensures the page is loaded first
 new Form.Element.Observer(                    // Observes the text_field_tag every 2     seconds
  'search',
   2,
   respondToChange                         //refrences the function in the Layout      
   )                                         // on a change in search calls   respondToChange
  });

  </script>

  </div>
```

at the  tag i have

```
 <script>
 function respondToChange() {
 $('search').up('form').submit()            // The ".up finds the form in the DOM"
 };
 </script>
```

The code Doesn't seem to be working,it doesnt even respond

**please does any one know how to implement this functionality in a more efficient way**

i really need help with this

Comment: You could have a look at some good autocompletion plugins, [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for example.

Comment: have you looked at the jquery autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: There's also a [popular Rails integration of this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option is to use a pre-existing Script:

1. http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/
2. http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/

They created their own and it has a few features worth considering. Or even using.